# Intel XDK - Push via pushMobi

Tags: html, push-notification, intel, intel-xdk, appmobi

I have some generel questions about the notification-service of pushMobi.(http://developer.html5dev-software.intel.com/?q=node/114)

Is this service using the common notification bars of iOS and Android? Like the native push notifications?

Do I have to pay for it? Does somebody have experience with this? Is there a App on iOS or Android which is using this service?

For me it looks like this service is not very popular, but I cant understand why? At first glance is looks very nice.

Answer (score 1):

[This link helps a little.. synopsis below:](https://forums.html5dev-software.intel.com/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=3490)

> Re: PushMobi Active User question
>
> Postby IntelJohn » Tue Feb 12, 2013 8:23 am
>
> The authUser parameter and authpw parameter are used to verify the
>   identify the identity of the person/server requesting the push
>   message. They are the email address and the password for the appMobi
>   account you are sending a push message to.
>
> You do not need to sign up for a pushMobi subscription. You can just
>   start using pushMobi (assuming of course you have added the necessary
>   push code) http://www.appmobi.com/documentation/in ... E_PUSHMOBI As
>   pushMobi is a service of appMobi, it will make your app fall into one
>   of the following categories. Our system automatically picks up if you
>   should be in the monetized model or not. We can determine if you are
>   using any of our services (live updates, push, stats, ect). We can
>   also determine if you are using either IAP or our appAds. Based upon
>   those 2 things, and the number of MAU's that your app has, you are
>   placed into either the completely free category, first 100 users free
>   category, or the first 10,000 users free category.
>
> If you do not use any of our services in your app, your app is
>   completely free. If you use our services, but not IAP or appAds, then
>   you get 100 free MAU's. Users 100-10000 will cost you .25 cents. All
>   users above 10000 will only cost .10 cents. If you use our services,
>   and either IAP or appAds, then you get 10000 free MAU's. Each MAU
>   after 10000 will cost you .10

I am investigating the intel XDK and it does indeed look very good.. We'll see.
PushMobi it seems is still operated by AppMobi which intel acquired as part of its strategy to get the XDK into shape. Appmobi continue to offer the cloud service elements and (I guess) uses the XDK and the relationship with Intel to leverage sales. But going to the Appmobi website, I can't find anything to confirm costs of use etc. which is more than a little disconcerting.
Take a look yourself and please let me know if you find anything else.. there is a 'contact us' point which I might just use to ask the questions. There is no point in designing something in if the pricing model doesn't suit you.. and there is no indication in the post as to what that really is.. whats an 'MAU'? I guess a user, but how often charged? Monthly.. all far from obvious.
[Appmobi website](http://www.appmobi.com/)
There are plenty of other push notification services out there but it is a shame if this one is good and reasonably priced ..

Answer (score 0):

Its completely free and is a very cool service. You can follow the link to learn about it and how to use it.

[Push Notifications using Intel XDK](http://qnimate.com/push-notifications-using-intel-xdk/)

Answer (score 0):

The AppMobi push service is currently only available if you use the Intel XDK "legacy" builds, which have been deprecated and will eventually disappear from the Intel XDK build system (no specific schedule for removal at the time of this post).

If AppMobi publishes a Cordova plugin for their push service it will then be available to anyone who uses the Intel XDK to build Cordova apps, or any other Cordova build system (such as Cordova CLI and PhoneGap) that allows for the use of third-party Cordova plugins.